# How to add background music to Html page?

Tags: html, audio, mp3

I'm trying some techniques I found on the Internet to play background music in Html. The music plays if I use controls and click on play. I'm trying:

```
<audio autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="runaway.mp3" /> 
</audio>
```

It doesn't seem to work on Chromium or Firefox. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```html
<audio src="song.mp3" controls="controls">
</audio>
```

Try this! Hope it'll help

Comment: I need it to start as soon as the page is loaded. The solution you provide works only if I press 'play'.

Comment: @DrimadesBoy That's not something you can do these days.  Auto-play has been all but removed, due to the feature being abused over the years.

Comment: @drimadesBoy https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_autoplay.asp
Check this out. You have to use `autoplay` this only to autoplay